# Looking for a young adult book about an audiovisual recording device that can rewind and fast-forward past the limits of the recording

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read it in the early 90s, I think, although it might of course be older. It was a short book, under 100 pages, probably under 50, and I think I read it as a paperback. A boy acquires a device that he can hook up to a TV (part of me wants to say that it's a VCR, but I don't think it actually had tapes or other storage media to insert and remove) and record things. He finds that he can rewind or fast forward the events outside of the area recorded; for example, I recall he records a parade and then rewinds earlier than when he was recording to see events there and I'm pretty sure that he uses it to see the future as well (I don't remember if it was established whether this was deterministic). Unfortunately, the rest of the details have escaped my head over the years.

For some reason, I want to say that the machine in question was green, although I have no firm idea why that idea is stuck in my head. I'm pretty sure that it was operated by large buttons too, not dials.

Comment: Oooohhhh!!!! I know i have read this at some point in my life! I cant remember much from it. Or what its called, unfortunately.

Comment: Reading the title reminded me about "The Ring" where the tape is forced to show extra details, but reading the text I think you are not looking for "The Ring" :/-- anyway I'm sure I readed something similiar too.

Comment: Heh. That's the most frustrating part yet. Everyone seems to have heard of it, but can't remember where.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter - Can you remember anything that Fuzzyboots didn't?

Comment: [This isn't it, but it is a similar principle](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/137974.The_Eternal_Enemy)

Comment: I tried for so long on this one last year...

Comment: @Praxis - We can do this! Ask your local librarians, booksellers, whatever!

Comment: [I found another one that isn't it, but is similar.](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/not-a-star-and-otherwise-pandemonium-nick-hornby/1111476437)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, I found a movie called [Jim's Gift (1996)](http://www.dvdverdict.com/reviews/jimsgift.php). Apparently it is based on a [very obscure novel by Sylvia Wickham](https://www.thereadingroom.com/book/jims-gift/677454/)

Comment: "When Jim gets home, he tries the VCR, which has an interesting feature: Jim can see events from his past—from birth to just a few moments ago. He uses this to find some lost money and the like, leaving his parents thinking he's psychic. Soon Jim finds Bossy, but he's not done with the VCR. Naturally, he won't be able to resist pushing that fast-forward, and when he starts trying to foil robberies that haven't happened yet and picking horse races, there's trouble. When trouble hits, the stranger repossesses the VCR, which means Jim and a pal must solve a mystery themselves."

Comment: From the movie description. Fastforward+rewind+1990s. Could this be it?

Comment: Huh... that does sound like a possible match, although the name doesn't sound familiar.

Comment: The book is incredibly obscure though: https://www.amazon.ca/Jims-Gift-Sylvia-Wickham/dp/0006749453. Look at the cost. Only the movie seems (very relatively) well-documented. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0219104/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt\

Comment: @Jonah:
If you post it as an answer, that's good for an upvote from me (and potentially a bounty auto-awarded), although it's not enough for me to accept it unless more evidence or my ILL request comes up.

Comment: The subtitle is "Fastforward the future," btw.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - You said that "everyone seems to have heard of it." Maybe some of those other "everyones" might recognize it?

Comment: @albusseveruspotter - Take a look: Could this be what you remember?

Comment: @DarioOO - Could this be what you read?

Comment: Nope, it is not that, it is possible I had just a dejavu. I have dozen of books that contains mini sci-fi stories, but noone with such title @Jonah

Comment: I've been trying to find the author, without much luck.

Comment: @Jonah: Although part of the issue there is that what they find might not turn out to be my story...

Comment: No, I mean if I can find the author, I might be able to find out whether the boy recorded a parade. I think it's pretty likely that this is your story, but that would clinch it. BTW do you remember which country you read the story in?

Comment: @Jonah: United States. Ashland, KY to be specific. And yeah, I tried checking if the local library had a copy of *Jim's Gift*. They don't, but that doesn't surprise me... Like most libraries, they get rid of old books pretty quickly. And most of the people who were librarians back then have retired if they're still alive.

Comment: Just to rule out another one, I read *[A Billion for Boris](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/808095.A_Billion_for_Boris)*, aka *ESP T.V.*, about a trio of kids and a television that shows the news for tomorrow, and it's also ultimately not a match.

Answer (score 8):

### Could this be *Jim's Gift: Fast Forward the Future*?

There is a very obscure movie called *[Jim's Gift](http://www.dvdverdict.com/reviews/jimsgift.php)*, released in 1996.

[image]

It was based on an even more obscure novel by an equally obscure author named Sylvia Wickham, written in 1994.

[image]

According to the movie description:

> When Jim gets home, he tries the VCR, which has an interesting
>   feature: Jim can see events from his past—from birth to just a few
>   moments ago. He uses this to find some lost money and the like,
>   leaving his parents thinking he's psychic. Soon Jim finds Bossy, but
>   he's not done with the VCR. Naturally, he won't be able to resist
>   pushing that fast-forward, and when he starts trying to foil robberies
>   that haven't happened yet and picking horse races, there's trouble.
>   When trouble hits, the stranger repossesses the VCR, which means Jim
>   and a pal must solve a mystery themselves.

I can't find any book description.

There are some IMDB reviews [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0219104/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt) that offer additional details.

This fits several of the criteria, assuming that the book is similar to the movie:

1. It was published in the early 90s (1994), and features
2. a VCR that
3. can record the past and the future and
4. probably is controlled by buttons, not dials (to judge from the book cover).
5. The main character is a boy.
6. It is 96 pages (under 100, though not under 50).

Note that the machine on the cover of the movie poster does seems sort of green.

Comment: Still trying to locate a copy somewhere (I have a request in with ILL), but this is close enough for the bounty. Congrats!

Comment: The ILL won't send it to me. The copy isn't being lent. I'm going to look at some alternate venues.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - You found a library with this book? Where?

Comment: Actually, re-reading, no. They couldn't find it at all. I confused it with a different ILL request where they offered to loan it, but only if I paid them $20.

Comment: Google Books gives a short blurb about the book: "When Jim buys a video recorder from a car boot sale, the whole family is thrilled. But when Jim fiddles with the extra feature, he discovers things that threaten to make his life just a little bit too exciting. Can a video predict the future, or is Jim just digging himself deeper into trouble?"  I'm not sure how much you can trust that, since it also says the book is from 1909, which is almost certainly an error. https://books.google.hu/books?id=wsYGNQAACAAJ

Comment: @b_jonas - No library has the book. The best bet would be to contact the author directly, but all I have is a name.

Comment: @b_jonas - Already done. Lots of 3 AM phone calls, but they are as stumped as I am.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Yes, I understand you can't find the book. I just mention the blurb because maybe it matches or contradicts something FuzzyBoots remembers.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: ...which means I should ping him, because SE doesn't send him a message about comments on an answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I suspect @FuzzyBoots has already seen that, though.

Comment: I have seen it. Unfortunately, it's not enough to confirm it. Maybe I just had a rare experience as a child, getting to read it. :)